# Block of HTML missing from rendered output

Tags: asp.net, iis, webforms

I manage a .NET webforms site which has had a strange issue since before I worked here. Every now and then it throws a  *System.Web.HttpException: A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:)* error email.

The error comes from random parts of random pages within the site and the last one I noticed had this entry against the CGI script_name:

```
SCRIPT_NAME /Scrienu_6 { border-style:none; }.SystemMenu_7 { background-color:
```

Looking at the rendered code for the page, it looks like a packet has been dropped near the head of the response and it's slicing off the end of the src portion of a script tag down to partway through an inline style block.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/DisableTheScreen.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
.floatingMenu
{
margin-top: 0px;
}
</style>
<link href="../App_Themes/siteTheme/Button.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../App_Themes/siteTheme/ConfirmBox.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../App_Themes/siteTheme/DisableBox.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../App_Themes/siteTheme/Panel.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../App_Themes/siteTheme/ResizableTextBox.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../App_Themes/siteTheme/Site.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="../App_Themes/siteTheme/Tabs.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
<style type="text/css">
.SystemMenu_0 { background-   color:white;visibility:hidden;display:none;position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px; }
.SystemMenu_1 { color:White;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:none; }
.SystemMenu_2 { color:White;font-weight:bold; }
.SystemMenu_3 { }
.SystemMenu_4 { background-color:#004A80; }
.SystemMenu_5 { background-color:#004A80; }
.SystemMenu_6 { border-style:none; }
.SystemMenu_7 { background-color:#004A80; }
```

So that it winds up slicing a chnk out of the middle eg:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scri

enu_6 { border-style:none; }
.SystemMenu_7 { background-color:#004A80; }
```

I've seen packet drops do fun things with images and unloaded CSS files in the past, but I've never seen them carve bits out of the rendered page content. I've googled the issue quite a bit but have not found anything similar so not sure if I'm even looking for the right problem.

The issue has only fired 22 times in the last 5 months on a fairly high-use system, but it's probably happening more frequently than that since we only see an error if a call back to the server has been borked with characters deemed unsafe by the request validator.

So yeah, just wondering if anyone has any ideas about what I can do or look for to solve this? :)

This behavior was observed in IIS7/Win2k8. It has also reportedly been observed in IIS8/Win2k12 and IIS8/Win8.1. I have seen no evidence of this in IIS6/Win2k3. It was last reported by two different customers of mine around November 2013. Neither of the server environments had VisualStudio installed. .NET Framework 2.0, 3.5, and 4.5[1?] were installed in both server enviros.

I have requested logs and full specs from both customers, and one of them has responded and confirmed that the issue no longer occurs. Therefore I suspect that either an update or hotfix from Msft addressed it, that it was network-related and has been resolved, or that Cthulhu decided to torment somebody else. The other customer has not yet responded.

Surely somebody else besides the OP and these customers must have seen this behavior? It would be nice to find a definitive answer and associate this problem with a known fix if possible. (And you get a sweet 200 pts.. yay!)

Comment: Not sure this would relate to you situation, but  a report of a similar-sounding issue can be found at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24155876/after-move-from-vs2010-to-vs2012-html-rendering-is-intermittently-losing-content)

Comment: Ahh thanks Jim, definitely looks similar and change from VS2010 to 2012 could have had some effect. We aren't experiencing the issue on any dev boxes though, only on our IIS 7 production server. I can't try any of the suggested changes from that post as we're under a change freeze right now, but the site's being rebuilt for MVC so hopefully it will be resolved with our next release.

Comment: Maybe you could test if Event Validation is causing your problem by disabling it for the mentioned page. Page.EnableEventValidation   = false; - Since the colon (:) seems to be the Problem you could also try to query the page with some "fake" colon queryfields (e.g. http://url?test:1). Colons might cause the problem because it can be used for "injection attacks" (accessing file System etc.)

Comment: The heart of the issue is that an entire chunk of the HTTP response is missing. Changing the content is irrelevant since it works in most environments with exactly the same code and content.

Comment: I hate to point out the obvious, but it is not possible to explain the problem without more evidence; what you will get is just conjecture. Have you had seen this other SO link: [What can cause TCP/IP to drop packets without dropping the connection?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/787415/what-can-cause-tcp-ip-to-drop-packets-without-dropping-the-connection)

Comment: Funny that you post this, a colleague of mine had a similar problem. Turning on compression in IIS fixes it, but we're unsure why it works. See if it works for you?

Comment: have you tried recreating it and monitoring where it fails with Fiddler (http://www.telerik.com/fiddler)?

Comment: Unfortunately I haven't been able to replicate the issue in our Local, Dev, or Test environments so haven't been able to see what's happening via Fiddler or anything else. The compression idea of @arao6 might do the trick though - I'll have a chat with the product owner and see if we can trial that.Will report back with the results.

Comment: I know there was an IE 8 bug that plagued our sites. Does this happen on all browsers?
http://forums.iis.net/t/1163765.aspx?Invalid+viewstate+The+Missing+4k+Bug+with+IE8

Comment: Mostly they're IE8 - but that's mainly because the bulk of our users internal and the standard operating environment is IE8... still... The logs do show the issue occuring for the occasional copy of FireFox or Chrome though, but definitely IE8 is the lions share.

Comment: At times, we had problems with dropped content AT THE END of the output, when using GZip compression. I figured, it was some problem with the reported length  of the the HTTP content, and added some excess spaces to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Does your request url has any *,
This may lead to such situation.

**

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="&lt;,&gt;,%,&amp;,:,\,?" />
</system.web>
```

**

you can add this to your web config to get it right

Comment: Could you possibly also link to a source where you get this information from? Or is it from experience?

Comment: no this website definitely has no special characters in the URLs. This was the first thing we checked throughout :) Users aren't adding funky things to the address either except when we've asked them to.

Comment: Do you have a file upload section in you webform.....
which is managed poorly
while doing such thing you can see this,
Because I have encountered such issue

Comment: The error hasn't occurred in any of the file upload areas the system has. It mainly happens on our internal search screen - but I think that's mainly because it's the page everyone starts on and winds up back on after doing anything.

Comment: Can you send the iis settings so that it can be much more clear.


If possible the stack trace.... too

Answer (score 0):

It Could be the issue of the file up loader that hasn't been managed well.

And Other potentially dangerous request can come through if you are using any editor to upload content. you need to manage if this is the scenario.
You can disable validation on that page where you are using Editor.
You can describe the validation mode in web.config like this.

Comment: I don't believe it's related to file uploads because it can occur anywhere in the site but mainly on a pure search screen (primarily because this is the most hit page on the site).

The issue isn't that users are trying to send dodgy URLs to the site, the issue is that the site is giving them malformed code that can sometimes truncate URLs in script and stylesheet links so that they lose a chunk from the end of the tag and being including following code as part of the URL when they try to load whichever resource from the server. Wow that was a heck of a run-on sentence, sorry :)

Answer (score -2):

Add

`<pages validateRequest="false"/>`

in web.config.

Comment: Nope!! this is a bad idea this will disable default request valaidation for ASp.NET and opens a security hole if done in production. You are asking for XSS and CSRF trouble  :)

Comment: As **JackOfAllTrades** said, if you do this you are asking for trouble. request validation happens for a good reason and should only be disabled in exceptional circumstances with alternative protection in place. Otherwise your site, and potentially others on the server, is open to cross site scripting attacks and all sorts of other unwanted nasty's :) @user2910624, apologies if what I said sounds rude in any way I only wanted to inform of the dangers.