# After move from VS2010 to VS2012 HTML rendering is intermittently losing content

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2012, webforms

We have updated our development environment from VS2010 to VS2012 but noticed the following issue: The start of the page is sometimes not rendered.

for example having something like:

```
<html>
  <head>
  <title>Title</title>
  <script>
    function myFunc() {...}
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    Content
  </body>
</html>
```

Might sometimes be rendered as:

```
yFunc() {...}
  </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    Content
  </body>
</html>
```

This only happens when using the VS2012 development server, IIS and VS2010 development server work correctly. Also the issue seem to appear randomly on all pages (for 20-30% of the requests).

NOTE: The application uses WebForms and .NET 3.5

Comment: did you make sure that your target framework in web.config is 3.5?

Comment: @JalpeshVadgama: yes, the target is set to 3.5.

Comment: Is this just happening for one developer or multiple developers?  Also, when you say you "updated our development environment" did you upgrade those machines from VS 2010 to VS 20112 or did you do clean installs of VS 2012 after uninstalling VS 2010?

Comment: @JimMSDN: It's a machine with a clean Windows 8.1 and VS2012 installation. There was no VS2010 previously installed. Also VS2012 has the latest upgrades, and there were no errors during install. This happened on one machine and the rest of us delayed the upgrade. We will do a new install for VS2012 and see if it helps. Thing is everything else works just fine (WPF projects, VC++ projects)

Comment: Does the missing content always appear in relation to the `head` and `script` tags? I have seen similar behavior at customer sites, often it cuts off a script tag halfway and generates this error: "A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected..." **I posted a 200 pt bounty** on the other question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18907524/block-of-code-missing-from-rendered-output

Comment: @nothingisnecessary: yes, it always appeared in the script tags located in my head section, but the exact location would sometimes shift a few characters and it only seemed to happen on big pages (> 3000 lines of html source code). Anyhow as my answer states the problem appeared only on one computer and never since...

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Seems the problem is related to this one computer. The problem did not occur on other computers, but a re-install did not help.

Seems there is really nothing that can be done...

Comment: I have seen this behavior at some of our client's sites, but not all of them. Perhaps a problem with a corrupt / buggy / unpatched .NET install? It's inconsistent and I have not been able to repro in a dev environment, only seen in a few prod sites.

Comment: @nothingisnecessary that is what I first thought, but I did a re-install of .net framework, VS, IIS. I didn't go quite as far as to do a complete windows re-install. But you are right, it looks either as a problem with a windows component (not necessarily .net) or a hardware/driver problem especially since the computer did blue screen a few time after a fresh install of Windows 8.1, but since we got rid of that one computer we have not seen this problem.